# Sur « avec le sens duquel » , « avec le sens de laquelle », etc

Tags: accord, pronoms-relatifs, subordonnées, morphologie

Quand l’antécédent de *duquel* est un nom au féminin, est-qu'on écrit *de laquelle*, « avec le sens de laquelle » ?

Comment: Pouvez-vous nous donner une phrase?? Personellement, j'ai du mal à m'en imaginer une. Avec le sens de laquelle, serait, en l'occurence, avec le sens dont .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est difficile de trouver une phrase non artificielle qui contient cette construction avec le nom *sens*, mais grammaticalement la construction existe et on utilise bien *duquel* ou *de laquelle* selon le genre de l'antécédent.

Par exemple,

- *avec le secours de laquelle*
- *avec le concours de laquelle*

donnés par une recherche avec [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avec+le+*+de+laquelle&corpus=7) sont parfaitement naturels.

Comment: Merci. J’étais très sûr que cette construction est correcte.

Answer (score 4):

La forme correcte de « avec le sens duquel » ou « avec le sens de laquelle » est

**"Le sens avec lequel"**

Sinon, "duquel" devient bien "de laquelle" avec un antécédent féminin.

> Par exemple : La chambre est **la pièce** dans **laquelle** il dort.

1. Masculin Singulier : duquel
2. Masculin Pluriel : desquels
3. Féminin Singulier : de laquelle
4. Féminin Pluriel : desquelles

Duquel (et ses formes accordées) s'utilise pour situer des choses.

> Par exemple : ... au dessous duquel ...
>
> Par exemple : ... au dessous de laquelle ...

Cependant, dans ton cas, avec le mot **sens**, la forme la plus simple à utiliser est "le sens **avec lequel**". En effet, "le sens **duquel**" n'est pas cohérent dans ce contexte.

Comment: Et « avec le sens de laquelle » ?

Comment: Peux-tu me faire une phrase complète ? Pour que je sois sûr de bien comprendre.

Comment: 1. La phrase suivante est celle avec le sens de laquelle je joue comme si elle était un jouet mental. 2. La phrase suivante est celle à laquelle je ne peux pas m'accoutumer.

Comment: La deuxième phrase est correcte. Par contre pour la première il serait beaucoup plus simple de dire : Le sens de la phrase suivante est celui **avec lequel** je joue comme si elle était un jouet mental.

Comment: Je ne crois pas que _le sens avec lequel_ et _le sens duquel_ signifient la même chose. Au moins en anglais, la première syntagme veut dire "the sense with which" et la seconde eyntagme veut dire "the sense of which" (or "whose sense"). Donc la mienne est, peut-être, correcte aussi.

Comment: @user26328 Even if "**avec** le sens duquel" were "idiomatic" ... (and I think Valentin is correct in saying that it's not (I do think, however that "**sur** le sens duquel" and "**dans** le sens duquel" would be ok in the right context [but not necessarily in yours]) ... I don't think that "[avec/sur/dans] le sens **de laquelle**" would ever be correct because as I interpret it, "**le** sens" is the real antecedent (not "la phrase"), and since it's masculine, "duquel." would seem to always be the right choice. (all of which to be taken with a grain of salt, as I'm a non-native speaker)

Comment: @PapaPoule I have never said that that combination of words is idiomatic. My comment above yours, and to which you replied a very little while ago, is about something else altogether.

Comment: Le mot "**duquel**" est très peu utilisé en français. On ne peut l'utilise que dans certains contextes bien précis (localisation) et avec un niveau de langue soutenu. Je conseil de ne pas utiliser ce mot. (Surtout à l'oral)

Comment: @user26328 I wasn't replying to your comment, but I'll do so here by saying that I totally agree with the difference you note between "le sens avec lequel" and "le sens duquel."  My earlier comment was trying to address the question you asked in your initial question, i.e., "... est-qu'on écrit **de laquelle**,  avec **le** sens **de laquelle** » ?

Comment: Si le sujet est **masculin** on utilise "**duquel**". Si le sujet est **féminin** on utilise "**de laquelle**". C'est plutôt simple comme règle. (le mot "sens" est masculin)

Comment: @PapaPoule I see. My apologies then. I am a little edgy because some fellas have decided to pick on me on the English page, without any apparent reason. Trolls disguised in scholarly garb. The worst kind there is.

Comment: Si on va imaginer une telle phrase, on aurait tendance à dire: avec le sens ***dont*** l'actrice se régale.